# What is a good penalty weighting function to maximize utilization?

Tags: optimization, optaplanner, weighting, timefold

I'm currently working on solving a VRP with Optaplanner/Timefold. We have the requirement to not only optimize towards low overall tour time/distance but also towards high vehicle utilization.

Our goal for e.g. 4 Vehicles would look like this schematic, where `x` stands for a load (note that this schematic is just for visualizing the question and the actual model is more realistic ;) ):

```
Vehicle 1 |x|x|x|
Vehicle 2 |x|x|x|
Vehicle 3 |x| | |
Vehicle 4 | | | |
```

So basically we would like to use as few vehicles with as close to full utilization as possible (which is a hard optimization problem in itself I guess). However, we are currently sometimes getting results a little more like this:

```
Vehicle 1 |x|x| |
Vehicle 2 |x|x| |
Vehicle 3 |x|x| |
Vehicle 4 |x| | |
```

What we've decided to try for now, is penalizing vehicles with deviations from full utilization linearly until a certain threshold and then give a bigger soft constant soft penalty to entities (except for unused vehicles). However, I think this might just move the vehicle utilizations towards said threshold and then be kind of random again.

Another idea we've had is just giving a penalty to every vehicle in use.

Are there other and better approaches to achieve the first result with a higher probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ideas how this could be achieved. What is surprising is that you seem to be getting well load-balanced vehicles out of the box; typically there need to be constraints that take care of load-balancing. In this case, what you seem to need is an actual anti-load-balancing constraint. Take a look at our article on [measuring unfairness](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2017/02/03/FormulaForMeasuringUnfairness.html), which could give you some pointers.

Sufficiently penalizing every vehicle in use, as you suggest, should certainly help with keeping vehicle use down.

Comment: Since we currently are not developing with a vastness of different datasets, it might also be that our data is coincidentally structured in a way that promotes the observed behaviour... Thanks for the pointer to the blogpost :)